# What is it called when a reflection of a person comes out to speak to him?

Tags: phrase-requests

Many a times in movies,plays etc a person's internal debate is shown by two similar people coming out - generally one dressed in white and other in black, debating with each other to bring the mind of the protagonist to a conclusion.(many times leaving him in confusion)

How can it be written in words?
Is there a specific word we use to write them?
Or any phrase as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commonly called [Good Angel, Bad Angel](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoodAngelBadAngel) (tvtropes.org):

> When someone wrestles with a temptation, two miniature versions of himself, an Angel and a Devil, sit on each shoulder and try to pull him in different directions. ... Alternatively, ... [they] may manifest as life-sized people on either side of the conflicted character rather than as miniatures on his shoulders.
>
> The technical, if somewhat dated, term for this is the Psychomachia ("Battle of the Soul"); in its original version, this implied a full-scale war between all of an individual's personified virtues (such as Humility, Chastity, Patience, etc.) against his personified vices (Pride, Lust, Anger, etc.).

Wikipedia notes that [The Psychomachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychomachia) is the title of a fifth-century poem that "is probably the first and most influential "pure" medieval allegory." However, the article goes on to say:

> The word may be used more generally for the common theme of the "battle between good and evil", for example in sculpture.